# Poor performance on Ubuntu 16.04 with R9 290 in CS:GO

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, steam, amd-graphics

I finally installed Ubuntu 16.04 after being on windows for a while and I have a problem. I went to the AMD site and I downloaded and installed the latest drivers for my video card - R9 290 for ubuntu 16.04, following the instructions provided.

I rebooted and added my user to the video group as they instructed. Installed steam and CS:GO, and when I hop in the game, fps is lower than 100fps (close to 300 in Windows 10), and there is a lot of micro stutter. Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT: Here's some info I pulled for my system:

```
$ inxi -GCS
System:    Host: mivanchev-Home Kernel: 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Unity 7.4.0  Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-2600K (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3800 MHz 1: 1631 MHz 2: 1690 MHz 3: 1671 MHz
           4: 1603 MHz 5: 1607 MHz 6: 1926 MHz 7: 1604 MHz 8: 1711 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series
           GLX Version: 4.5.13462 - CPC 16.50.5
```